# How to serve two sites with one nginx docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have one webapp which is built with npm webpack, generate a folder, I push the folder to a centos folder, and start a nginx docker to serve it, it works fine, some files are as following:
nginx.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.14.0
        volumes:
            - ./../www:/usr/share/nginx/html
            # ./../www is /home/example1/www
            - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
        ports:
            - "443:443"
            - "80:80"
```

and site.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name example1.com www.example1.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ssl related ...

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://www.example1.com:8080/api;
    }
}
```

Now I want to serve another site (e.g. example2.com), so I generate another folder with npm webpack, push it to /home/example2/www, because this time nginx will serve two site, I remove

```
- ./../www:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

from nginx.yml
and add one server section with port 8081 to site.conf, and add

```
root /home/example1/www;
root /home/example2/www;
```

in each server section of site.conf. However both sites not work, I searched on internet, most of posts suggest setup a nginx-proxy, and host each webapp on other docker container.

Is it possible for one nginx docker container to serve two sites? 
and How?

Comment: Ngnix has built in reverse proxy support, so the answer is yes.  But one massive advantage of Docker is it's micro services approach.

Comment: Thanks, limited by the server amount, the simpler the solution, the better. could you please tell why above config not work?

Comment: Are you trying to do two websites with one domain but by using prefixes such as `/api`

Comment: two sites: example1.com and example2.com, both access web api application in the same host (another spring boot docker), I doubt removing ./../www: /usr/share/nginx/html causes the issue.

Comment: found the solution, create two folders in container, and save the container to a new image, in nginx.yml create two volumes. will post answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The nginx image includes all *.conf files that are located in /etc/nginx/conf.d.  Try running this to verify: `docker run --rm -it nginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

So that means you should be able to put as many conf files there that you want, and nginx will serve it.

So that means you could volumize site files and the conf file like so:

```
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.14.0
        volumes:
            - ./../www:/usr/share/nginx/html
            - ./../example1:/home/example1/www
            - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./nginx/site2.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site2.conf
```

in site2.conf:

```
server_name example2.com www.example2.com;

location / {
    root /home/example1/www;
}
```

Comment: yes, except, need create new image based on running container, because the original image does not include /home/example1/www, which will be disappear after next restart.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that.  You're saying that example1 source files are not in the same place as example2?

Comment: yes, example1 and example2 are different applications

Comment: Like different Dockerfiles?  Why do you say example1/www will "disappear after next restart"?  I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: I mean /home/example1/www is not part of nginx image

Comment: you add `/home/example1/www` to a volume in docker-compose.yml